# utf-8 encoding in HTML and utf8_unicode_ci char set & collation for MySQL - can I store & display any type of text in it now?

Tags: php, mysql, localization

I want to dvp a small web app which would ideally be used worldwide.  For the sake of the discussion, let's say it's a recipe sharing site - it's a good enough metaphor.

My app will allow users to enter or upload text in their native languages.  My html header says that the site uses utf-8 encoding.  I am now creating my MySQL db, and I suppose that I should select utf8_unicode_ci for the char set & collation.

Is that correct?

Is that all I need to do to be able to receive, store, and display safe user-generated-content in their chosen language?  If not, what am I missing?

(I am aware of the safety concerns associated with displaying UGC, this is not what the question is about - here I am solely looking for advice to deal with safe content.)

Comment: Also, I have saved the php files using UTF-8 encoding.  I forgot to mention this when I initially wrote the question, and I have encountered files with proper encoding that didn't displayed well because they were saved in the ANSI format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all for you HTML and DB part, but you must ensure that the programming language is UTF-8 aware so it doesn't garble your stuff. If you use PHP just make sure that the functions you use are UTF-8 aware. If it isn't the manual usually mentions it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the html and the db i think this is all you need.
The only other part you may need to define that your inputs are UTF-8 encoded, is the part where you send/receive your data (assuming with a form and a post request for example).
You can check post #:1281123 in this [forum](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/3543.htm), it helped a lot when i had some problems with encoding in a similar situation.